# mysql how to see rows that has same number in different column

Tags: mysql

I need to display (and even reverse the query not see) the rows that have the same value in different column. In this case, for example: line n. 01,02,05,07. These are results of an esitent query that creates a view executed on multiple tables, with different JOINs, maybe I should use only the WHERE clause at the bottom of the query. (#) Is not id of the table.

Column1, Column2 from tableA 
ColumnX.. other table.

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
|                          View1                         |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| #  | Column1 | Column2 | ColumnX | ColumnX | ColumnX.. |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 01 |    28   |    24   | value   | value   | ...       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 02 |    24   |    0    | value   | value   | ...       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 03 |    30   |    0    | value   | value   | ...       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 04 |    25   |    0    | value   | value   | ...       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 05 |    15   |    13   | value   | value   | ...       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 06 |    18   |    0    | value   | value   | ...       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
| 07 |    13   |    0    | value   | value   | ...       |
+----+---------+---------+---------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: Your expected output does not make sense. None of your columns match.

Comment: Do you mean you want to see a row if a value in column 2 has a matching value in a successive row in column 1?

Comment: I tried {} but did not put in the table

Comment: if a value in column 2 has a matching value in a successive row in column 1 and  if a value in column 1 has a matching value in a successive row in column 2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
           FROM my_table x 
           JOIN my_table y 
             ON y.id <> x.id 
            AND (y.column1 = x.column2 OR y.column2 = x.column1);
+----+---------+---------+
| id | column1 | column2 |
+----+---------+---------+
|  2 |      24 |       0 |
|  1 |      28 |      24 |
|  7 |      13 |       0 |
|  5 |      15 |      13 |
+----+---------+---------+
```

Comment: it's same table

Comment: the data is in the same table only table x, I can not use
FROM my_table x
JOIN my_table y

Comment: Why not? I just did

Comment: is a view of multiple tables, there is an error in my table before, not a view id, it was just a reference to specify the lines I needed. So the table is one and does not have the id field

Comment: I suggest you see [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and start over.

Comment: and what do you do?

Comment: I'm going to go eat pizza

Comment: Good idea why not!